# Unable to compile example from OpenCL C++ Bindings Documentation (cl2.hpp)

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to learn OpenCL2 with C++.
I'm using kubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and beignet from repository.
My laptop is a lenovo with a intel i5-5200U without nvidia or similar.
The command `clinfo` recognize the platform.
The first bug i found in the example is the variable `output2` that isn't declared i have tried to comment it, but still get many link error...
The example is this http://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/index.html#example

This is a minimal example that reproduce a part of link error:

main.cpp:

```
// Defines the target OpenCL runtime version to build the header against.
// Defaults to 200, representing OpenCL 2.0.
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200

#include <CL/cl2.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # C++11...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) #...is required...
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) #...without compiler extensions like gnu++11

project(exampleopencl2)

add_executable(exampleopencl2 main.cpp)

install(TARGETS exampleopencl2 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

I use KDevelop and i get this output when i try to compile this code:

```
/home/deglans/ExampleOpenCL2/build> make -j2 mytests
Scanning dependencies of target mytests
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/main2.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable mytests
CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/main2.cpp.o: In function `cl::detail::ReferenceHandler<_cl_device_id*>::release(_cl_device_id*)':
/usr/include/CL/cl2.hpp:1438: undefined reference to `clReleaseDevice'
CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/main2.cpp.o: In function `cl::detail::ReferenceHandler<_cl_context*>::release(_cl_context*)':
/usr/include/CL/cl2.hpp:1473: undefined reference to `clReleaseContext'
CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/main2.cpp.o: In function `cl::detail::ReferenceHandler<_cl_command_queue*>::release(_cl_command_queue*)':
/usr/include/CL/cl2.hpp:1482: undefined reference to `clReleaseCommandQueue'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'mytests' failed
make[3]: *** [mytests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:116: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mytests.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:175: recipe for target 'mytests' failed
make: *** [mytests] Error 2
*** Errore: Codice di uscita 2 ***
```

Comment: Are you linking against the OpenCL lib? Please post a [mcve]. Also, the OpenCL C++ bindings make me sad.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding `target_link_libraries(exampleopencl2 OpenCL)` in the CMakeLists.txt file.